# Java EE replacement for Scala?

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee, typesafe-stack

Many Java x Scala comparisons seem to focus on the language alone (syntax, collections api, actors, etc) but what about enterprise application development?

If you want to build a distributed enterprise system using Scala, would you code a traditional Java EE application using Scala syntax (e.g. EJB compatible class using Scala syntax) and run it in a Java EE container, or is there a Java EE replacement in the Scala ecosystem?

If the second, so far the closest thing I found is the typesafe stack; is it Scala's replacement for a Java EE container?

Is Akka a JMS (and possibly Session Beans) replacement or would your Scala system still leverage Java EE services?

Comment: forget JEE (container and others bloody entreprisy specs), embrace Scala libraries, use Akka RabbitMQ. And rediscover what programming really is: FUN!

Comment: In addition to Alois' comment (which I endorse fully) just put ORM in your rear-view mirror and go with Slick!

Comment: @aloiscochard I'm having tons of fun programming with Java EE, no need for Scala here ;)

Comment: @MikeBraun: I'm guessing you've never really used a decent programming language. "Fun" and "Java" do not belong in the same sentence...

Comment: @mccann who are you to decide that? I'm most definitely having a lot of fun writing very cool stuff in Java. If you're too blind and too much influenced by the hipsters then that's your bad.

Comment: @MikeBraun: I'm someone who expects a language to help more than it gets in the way, and has used enough languages to tell the difference. Java is objectively (ha, ha) a bad language, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 23):

Well,
Scala / Akka offer different concepts for many of the common pitfalls 
in system development. To compare just a few to Java EE:

=> JavaBeans:
Mutable Data-structures are just plain evil and not thread-safe. 
Putting them into a container doesn't change anything. 
Use immutable data structures instead, as scala enforces with CaseClasses.

=> EJB:
Composition of EJBs just sucks. The actual problem is that EJBs need to have a high level of cohesion to be useful in terms of re-usability which is hardly the case in practice. Stuffing them into a container wan't make it any better. In Scala, using traits,
for composition enables you to use ad-hoc composition through constructor injection protected by f-bounded polymorphism. Life can be so easy.

=> Transactions:
Yes transaction managers already make things better but it's still 
requires the big Java EE stack to make it work. In Scala, just use Software Transactional Memory (STM) as provided by akka and you're done.

=> Persistence:
Do we really need ORM? Projects like squeryl.org add strongly typed LINQ to Scala. 
Instead of heavy-weight query language mapping, as Hibernate does, it just integrates
queries into scala, fully checked by the compiler. This is of course only true for relational DB's. For no-sql, there are other solutions available.

=> Scaling?
Clustering Java EE? Do I need to say more?
In akka you just add a few more server and the system just scales. Why? Because
remote actors are treated and accessed the same way as local actors and everything
else is just a matter of configuring your distributed actor system. Akka is based on
the Erlang model, so they do not look for five-nine up-time but nine-nine up-time
under full system load. 
At the same time, akka is so easy and light-weight that you
can use it on Android. Would you try to run Java EE on Android?
https://github.com/gseitz/DiningAkkaDroids

To be clear, maybe ten years ago, Java EE was the answer to the question how to build 
large enterprise grade software and, once Spring has made it usable, it was maybe the best available solution at those days.
Today, the world has changed a lot and most of the old answers do not fit today's reality anymore. Scala, is not perfect but if it really comes down to one single line it would b be this:

In scala, I get my actual programming done in a fraction of time the Java EE 
and container setup would take.

Even Spring, as the framework of choice for Java EE is moving towards scala:

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/12/10/introducing-spring-scala/

To start with both, concepts and best practices for Akka, there is a handy 
book called "Akka Essential"

http://www.akkaessentials.in/2012/12/adding-turbchargers-to-jee-apps.html

Comment: J2EE is indeed almost a decade old. These days we have Java EE. Have you been caught up with that?

Comment: Thanks, your right, I've fixed that typo. Indeed I'm out of J2EE / JEE for a while but do the underlying issues really have changed?

Comment: Regarding no-SQL and other sources or repositories or formats for external data, Slick's upcoming "type providers" extend the LINQ concept to non-SQL sources.

Comment: Nice post, but case classes can be mutable as well: `case class Foo(var x: Int)` is absolutely valid.

Comment: > `transaction managers already make things better but it's still requires the big Java EE stack` - TomEE is fully transactional and is 25MB in size. For the *entire* download.

Comment: > `Would you try to run Java EE on Android?` - Well, it runs on the Raspberry Pi ;) http://delabassee.com/blog/?p=82

Comment: "Fraction of time a Java EE container setup takes" - you mean those 2 seconds it takes me to download and unzip TomEE, JBoss, Glassfish, Resin etc? It's download and unzip. Then everything is ready use. If you think some complicated install and setup is needed you're living 10 years in the past.

Comment: download and unzip? ever heard of maven? thanks god we've been using managed dependencies for 10 years

Comment: @OlegYch So you also fetch your OS, JVM and undoubtedly beloved Tomcat with Maven?

Comment: @dextermeyers there is other package manager for that, maven deal only with jvm artifacts, but pacman can install in very nice way jdk/tomcat/maven/.... or even sbt/scala if you are on the dark side

Comment: @aloiscochard so what's the issue then? Use apt-get or whatever to install the jdk and TomEE, use Maven for other stuff...

Comment: yes i would use netty/tomcat/jetty/glassfish embedded, the need for standalone "container" is just yet another delusion brought to you by JavaEE, sorry for digressing though

Comment: @MikeBraun sorry but I'm not understanding your question, where did I say there is an issue? I was responding to dexter meyers

Comment: I think that your are talking about J2EE when you said Java EE. Two completely different things. JavaEE did not exist 10 years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Akka is indeed a sort of "replacement" for JMS. Behind this idea (and your question) it is indeed a change of paradigm, and we must be aware of that, but starting from this fact i think akka had chance to be used very widely in the next future for several uses, from message passing to integration between distributed etherogeneus concurrent platform.

Typesafe stack is a stack, so i found unuseful to think that regarding Java EE contanier.

And last, the first answer: if you want to use the EJB syntax, please consider using annotations and you should have the chance to write EJB more or less in the same way as java, plus some "syntactic sugar" of scala

Comment: If you want to do a client/server application (not web), how would you do remoting for example if you dont want to use sessions beans or RMI? Would you use akka remote actors? What about distributed transactions, jndi, jdbc, etc.

Comment: I would say that Akka remoting, clustering and transactors features is enough to do what you need. For persistence there are differing choices available, from scala-only Slick to straight JPA. Refer to the rich [Akka documentation](http://akka.io/docs/) or some [book](http://www.artima.com/shop/akka_concurrency) from [those](http://www.packtpub.com/akka-java-applications-essentials/book) [available](http://www.manning.com/roestenburg/), to figure out how to get the most out of it. For alternative remote frameworks, non-web: [spray](http://spray.io/), [rapture](http://www.propensive.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want Java EE, you can go right ahead and use Java EE with Scala. However, I don't know anyone in the Scala community who doesn't want to get *away* from Java EE (or continue to avoid it).

Comment: I don't really want to stick to JEE; I'm just wondering what are the best practices in Scala for distributed enterprise systems :)